# Need webcam chat plugin for my client

Tags: plugin-recommendation

I am developing a website where I need a webcam chat plugin. I have tried many plugins from wordpress.org but none of them worked. Can anyone please suggest me a working plugin. 
Plugins that did not work:

1. TokBox OpenTok Plugin

**Problem**:

> In the dashboard,it only pops up once
>   i.e the first time the plugin is used
>   and still the button to start webcam
>   did not work(Also note that it did not
>   show up my webcam.)

**Resolved:**

The problem was with the dashboard. I uploaded the files and it started to work . Thanks
 2. Tinychat**

**Problem**:

> Was unable to find API for it.

1. VideoWhisper Video Presentation

**Problem**:

> Keeps on loading and does not work

Thanks.

Comment: So I guess you have a list of plugins and a description what worked/didn't work. Please post it as every Answer could be a repetition of something you already tried.

Comment: Yes, I have added some of them

Comment: (removed as I stumbled upon some maybe helpfull stuff)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the link to the API for [Tinychat](http://de.tinychat.com/developer/). It was hidden in the footer.

You could also take a look at [this thread on WeekendHackers](http://us2.campaign-archive1.com/?u=70988277cb322d150c4001f07&id=5f81a8134a&e=5103a2db5d#one), where someone is searching for the same solution. Maybe you can put your heads together :)

Answer (score 0):

Try [VideoWhisper Conference Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/videowhisper-video-conference-integration/)

Btw, if you were trying videowhisper video presentation with continuous loading, that means you need to check your hosting, make sure that it conforms to all the RMTP setup requirement.